# I need some help using dynamic sql in a table function

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with a third party application with an oracle back end.

I'm trying to store SQL that will then be passed to the database and display a list of results.

The problem is that when the application queries the DB it turns all single quotes into double single quotes. 
(select 'x' from dual becomes select ''x'' from dual)
So, I thought I could build a table function that would strip the extra single quotes and the execute the query, but I'm having problems.

```
create or replace type DSQLMenu_Record as object 
(
  label varchar2(255),
  value varchar2(255)
)
;--------------------------------------------------------------------
create or replace type DSQLMenu_Table as table of DSQLMenu_Record
;--------------------------------------------------------------------
create or replace function F_DSQLMenu (V_IN_QUERY in varchar2)
return DSQLMenu_Table as
    V_RESULTS        DSQLMenu_Table;
    V_PARSED_QUERY   VARCHAR2(8000);
begin
    V_PARSED_QUERY := replace(V_IN_QUERY,'''''','''') ;
    select 
      DSQLMenu_Record(label, value)
      bulk collect into
      V_RESULTS
      from 
          (
             execute immediate V_PARSED_QUERY;
          );
     return V_RESULTS;
end F_DSQLMenu;
```

If it were doing what I'd like, the user would click a drop-down menu in the application and see a list of results based on the sql query that was passed in.

Thanks.

Comment: P.B. you currently have not given enough information for people to assist you.  What is the problem you are having?  you have given some code where you strip the quotes and then execute an sql statement. Does this compile if not what is the compiler error you are recieving? if it does compile what happens when your run it? does it return results or an error?

Comment: The first two parts compile just fine.
When I try to compile the function, I get the following errors:  
- Error(6,1):PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored  
- Error(14,33):PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis  
- Error(15,13):PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for providing the extra details.  I think you would need to change your select around a bit.....

see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/11_dynam.htm for correct syntax.

So it would need to be something along the lines of the below (haven't got environment to test)

```
V_PARSED_QUERY := 'select DSQLMenu_record(label, value) from (' || v_parsed_query || ')';
execute immediate v_parsed_query bulk collect into v_results;
```

**UPDATE**

in answer to your comment....  I am not sure why you would be getting a single record.  As per the below code snippet I am getting two records correctly

```
declare

type DSQLMenu_Table is table of DSQLMenu_Record;

V_RESULTS        DSQLMenu_Table;
V_PARSED_QUERY   VARCHAR2(8000) := 'select ''The Test Value A'' thelabel, ''TestValA'' thevalue, 1 thesort from dual union select ''The Test Value B'' thelabel, ''TestValB'' thevalue, 2 thesort from dual order by thesort';

begin
V_PARSED_QUERY := 'select DSQLMenu_Record(thelabel, thevalue) from (' || v_parsed_query || ')';
dbms_output.put_line(v_parsed_query);

execute immediate v_parsed_query bulk collect into v_results;

dbms_output.put_line(v_results.count);

for i in v_results.first..v_results.last loop
   dbms_output.put_line(v_results(i).label);
end loop;

end;
```

the dbms output result is

```
    select DSQLMenu_Record(thelabel, thevalue) from (select 'The Test Value A' thelabel, 'TestValA' thevalue, 1 thesort from dual union select 'The Test Value B' thelabel, 'TestValB' thevalue, 2 thesort from dual order by thesort)
2
The Test Value A
The Test Value B
```

Comment: That made it WAY cleaner.  Here's what I have now:
    create or replace function F_DSQLMenu (V_IN_QUERY in varchar2)
    return DSQLMenu_Table as
       V_RESULTS        DSQLMenu_Table;
       V_PARSED_QUERY   VARCHAR2(8000);
    begin
       V_PARSED_QUERY := replace(V_IN_QUERY,'''''','''') ;
       V_PARSED_QUERY := 'select DSQLMenu_record(thelabel, thevalue) from (' || v_parsed_query || ')';
       execute immediate v_parsed_query bulk collect into v_results;
       return V_RESULTS;
    end F_DSQLMenu;
Result is: DBO.DSQLMENU_TABLE([DBO.DSQLMENU_RECORD], [DBO.DSQLMENU_RECORD])

Comment: I hate the formatting in comments... Anyway - your suggested edit was exactly what was needed. It's now acting like a hardcoded version of it I made that ditched the dynamic query for debug. But, the result is really weird.(and matched my hardcoded test.) Instead of two rows, I got 1 row that was really funny looking. I've used a table function in one other place in my code, and it's working flawlessly, so I can't figure out what's going on here. Any additional assistance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Here's a test query if you want to try to run it: select F_DSQLMenu('select ''The Test Value A'' thelabel, ''TestValA'' thevalue, 1 thesort from dual union select ''The Test Value B'' thelabel, ''TestValB'' thevalue, 2 thesort from dual order by thesort') from dual

Comment: That last problem came from how I was calling it.
------------------
Incorrect: select F_DSQLMenu('select ''The Test Value A'' thelabel, ''TestValA'' thevalue, 1 thesort from dual union select ''The Test Value B'' thelabel, ''TestValB'' thevalue, 2 thesort from dual order by thesort') from dual
------------------
Correct: select thelabel, thevalue from table(F_DSQLMenu('select ''The Test Value A'' thelabel, ''TestValA'' thevalue, 1 thesort from dual union select ''The Test Value B'' thelabel, ''TestValB'' thevalue, 2 thesort from dual order by thesort'))
------------------
Thanks again.